# Authentication vsftpd account using remote LDAP user

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, vsftpd, ldap, pam

I'm trying to authenticate vsftpd from LDAP logins which hosted remotely another server .

vsftpd hosted on `Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-48-generic x86_64)` amazon aws .

from the LDAP server i have these details .

```
user          :    cn=demo,dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com
Password :    testpasswd
Base DN   :   dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com
User Base :  ou=user,dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com
```

and a ca_serv.pem to authenticate which included in `/etc/ssl/certs/` and added references to `/etc/ldap/ldap.conf​` as `TLS_CACERT /etc/ssl/certs/ca_serv.pem`

my `/etc/pam.d/vsftpd` is like this .

```
# Standard behaviour for ftpd(8).
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required      pam_shells.so

auth    required        pam_ldap.so
account required        pam_ldap.so
session sufficient      pam_ldap.so
password        required        pam_ldap.so
session required        pam_ldap.so
```

when i commented `auth required  pam_shells.ssufficiento` in here I no longer can `ftp  localhost` to users created locally.

`/etc/ldap.conf` file

```
###DEBCONF###
##
## Configuration of this file will be managed by debconf as long as the
## first line of the file says '###DEBCONF###'
##
## You should use dpkg-reconfigure to configure this file via debconf
##

#
# @(#)$Id: ldap.conf,v 1.38 2006/05/15 08:13:31 lukeh Exp $
#
# This is the configuration file for the LDAP nameservice
# switch library and the LDAP PAM module.
#
# PADL Software
# http://www.padl.com
#

# Your LDAP server. Must be resolvable without using LDAP.
# Multiple hosts may be specified, each separated by a 
# space. How long nss_ldap takes to failover depends on
# whether your LDAP client library supports configurable
# network or connect timeouts (see bind_timelimit).
#host 127.0.0.1

# The distinguished name of the search base.
#base dc=example,dc=net
base  dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com

# Another way to specify your LDAP server is to provide an
# Unix Domain Sockets to connect to a local LDAP Server.
#uri ldap://127.0.0.1/
```

uri ldaps://ldap.foobar.com:636

```
# Note: %2f encodes the '/' used as directory separator

# The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3
# if supported by client library)
ldap_version 3

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with.
# Optional: default is to bind anonymously.
#binddn cn=proxyuser,dc=padl,dc=com

# The credentials to bind with. 
# Optional: default is no credential.
#bindpw secret

# The distinguished name to bind to the server with
# if the effective user ID is root. Password is
# stored in /etc/ldap.secret (mode 600)
#rootbinddn cn=manager,dc=example,dc=net
rootbindddn cn=foo,dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com

# The port.
# Optional: default is 389.
#port 389

# The search scope.
#scope sub
#scope one
#scope base

# Search timelimit
#timelimit 30

# Bind/connect timelimit
#bind_timelimit 30

# Reconnect policy: hard (default) will retry connecting to
# the software with exponential backoff, soft will fail
# immediately.
#bind_policy hard

# Idle timelimit; client will close connections
# (nss_ldap only) if the server has not been contacted
# for the number of seconds specified below.
#idle_timelimit 3600

# Filter to AND with uid=%s
#pam_filter objectclass=account

# The user ID attribute (defaults to uid)
#pam_login_attribute uid

# Search the root DSE for the password policy (works
# with Netscape Directory Server)
#pam_lookup_policy yes

# Check the 'host' attribute for access control
# Default is no; if set to yes, and user has no
# value for the host attribute, and pam_ldap is
# configured for account management (authorization)
# then the user will not be allowed to login.
#pam_check_host_attr yes

# Check the 'authorizedService' attribute for access
# control
# Default is no; if set to yes, and the user has no
# value for the authorizedService attribute, and
# pam_ldap is configured for account management
# (authorization) then the user will not be allowed
# to login.
#pam_check_service_attr yes

# Group to enforce membership of
#pam_groupdn cn=PAM,ou=Groups,dc=padl,dc=com

# Group member attribute
#pam_member_attribute uniquemember

# Specify a minium or maximum UID number allowed
#pam_min_uid 0
#pam_max_uid 0

# Template login attribute, default template user
# (can be overriden by value of former attribute
# in user's entry)
#pam_login_attribute userPrincipalName
#pam_template_login_attribute uid
#pam_template_login nobody

# HEADS UP: the pam_crypt, pam_nds_passwd,
# and pam_ad_passwd options are no
# longer supported.
#
# Do not hash the password at all; presume
# the directory server will do it, if
# necessary. This is the default.
pam_password md5

# Hash password locally; required for University of
# Michigan LDAP server, and works with Netscape
# Directory Server if you're using the UNIX-Crypt
# hash mechanism and not using the NT Synchronization
# service. 
#pam_password crypt

# Remove old password first, then update in
# cleartext. Necessary for use with Novell
# Directory Services (NDS)
#pam_password clear_remove_old
#pam_password nds

# RACF is an alias for the above. For use with
# IBM RACF
#pam_password racf

# Update Active Directory password, by
# creating Unicode password and updating
# unicodePwd attribute.
#pam_password ad
# Use the OpenLDAP password change
# extended operation to update the password.
#pam_password exop

# Redirect users to a URL or somesuch on password
# changes.
#pam_password_prohibit_message Please visit http://internal to change your password.

# RFC2307bis naming contexts
# Syntax:
# nss_base_XXX        base?scope?filter
# where scope is {base,one,sub}
# and filter is a filter to be &'d with the
# default filter.
# You can omit the suffix eg:
# nss_base_passwd    ou=People,
# to append the default base DN but this
# may incur a small performance impact.
#nss_base_passwd    ou=People,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_shadow    ou=People,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_group        ou=Group,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_hosts        ou=Hosts,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_services    ou=Services,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_networks    ou=Networks,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_protocols    ou=Protocols,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_rpc        ou=Rpc,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_ethers    ou=Ethers,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_netmasks    ou=Networks,dc=padl,dc=com?ne
#nss_base_bootparams    ou=Ethers,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_aliases    ou=Aliases,dc=padl,dc=com?one
#nss_base_netgroup    ou=Netgroup,dc=padl,dc=com?one

# attribute/objectclass mapping
# Syntax:
#nss_map_attribute    rfc2307attribute    mapped_attribute
#nss_map_objectclass    rfc2307objectclass    mapped_objectclass

# configure --enable-nds is no longer supported.
# NDS mappings
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member

# Services for UNIX 3.5 mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount User
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount User
#nss_map_attribute uid msSFU30Name
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember msSFU30PosixMember
#nss_map_attribute userPassword msSFU30Password
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFU30HomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory msSFUHomeDirectory
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup Group
#pam_login_attribute msSFU30Name
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# RFC 2307 (AD) mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount user
#nss_map_objectclass shadowAccount user
#nss_map_attribute uid sAMAccountName
#nss_map_attribute homeDirectory unixHomeDirectory
#nss_map_attribute shadowLastChange pwdLastSet
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup group
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
#pam_login_attribute sAMAccountName
#pam_filter objectclass=User
#pam_password ad

# configure --enable-authpassword is no longer supported
# AuthPassword mappings
#nss_map_attribute userPassword authPassword

# AIX SecureWay mappings
#nss_map_objectclass posixAccount aixAccount
#nss_base_passwd ou=aixaccount,?one
#nss_map_attribute uid userName
#nss_map_attribute gidNumber gid
#nss_map_attribute uidNumber uid
#nss_map_attribute userPassword passwordChar
#nss_map_objectclass posixGroup aixAccessGroup
#nss_base_group ou=aixgroup,?one
#nss_map_attribute cn groupName
#nss_map_attribute uniqueMember member
#pam_login_attribute userName
#pam_filter objectclass=aixAccount
#pam_password clear

# Netscape SDK LDAPS
#ssl on

# Netscape SDK SSL options
#sslpath /etc/ssl/certs

# OpenLDAP SSL mechanism
# start_tls mechanism uses the normal LDAP port, LDAPS typically 636
#ssl start_tls
#ssl on

# OpenLDAP SSL options
# Require and verify server certificate (yes/no)
# Default is to use libldap's default behavior, which can be configured in
# /etc/openldap/ldap.conf using the TLS_REQCERT setting.  The default for
# OpenLDAP 2.0 and earlier is "no", for 2.1 and later is "yes".
#tls_checkpeer yes

# CA certificates for server certificate verification
# At least one of these are required if tls_checkpeer is "yes"
#tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/ca.cert
#tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs

# Seed the PRNG if /dev/urandom is not provided
#tls_randfile /var/run/egd-pool

# SSL cipher suite
# See man ciphers for syntax
#tls_ciphers TLSv1

# Client certificate and key
# Use these, if your server requires client authentication.
#tls_cert
#tls_key

# Disable SASL security layers. This is needed for AD.
#sasl_secprops maxssf=0

# Override the default Kerberos ticket cache location.
#krb5_ccname FILE:/etc/.ldapcache

# SASL mechanism for PAM authentication - use is experimental
# at present and does not support password policy control
#pam_sasl_mech DIGEST-MD5
```

`/etc/ldap/ldap.conf` content

```
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    BASE    dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666
```

URI ldaps://ldap.foobar.com ldaps://ldap.foobar.com:636

```
#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca_serv.pem    #
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    BASE    dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com
#URI    ldap://ldap.example.com ldap://ldap-master.example.com:666
URI     ldap://ldap_server_ip ldap://ldap_server_ip:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca_serv.pem
TLS_REQCERT allow
TLS_REQCERT allow
```

I also have `/etc/ldap.secret` file with password for `rootbindddn cn=foo,dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com` which on the `/etc/ldap.conf`

content of `/etc/vsftpd.conf`

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=NO
#
# Run standalone with IPv6?
# Like the listen parameter, except vsftpd will listen on an IPv6 socket
# instead of an IPv4 one. This parameter and the listen parameter are mutually
# exclusive.
listen_ipv6=YES
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default)
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
#chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
# This option specifies the location of the RSA key to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
#allow_writeable_chroot=YES
#pasv_enable=Yes
#pasv_min_port=40000
#pasv_max_port=40100
```

when i run the ldapsearch 
`ldapsearch ­-x ­-H ldaps://ldap.foobar.com:636 -b "dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com" -D "cn=foo,dc=ldap,dc=foobar,dc=com" -w'testpasswd'`

result is `ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)`

also `ftp localhost` says `ftp: connect: Connection refused'`

Comment: Did you manage to get it fully functional?